# How to talk about someone's age in a photo?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I want to talk about someone's age in two photos, one taken long before now, and one this year.

I think the older one should be like "He was 27 years old in this photo." But I can't figure out what to use with the newer one.

So what do you say when talking about someone's age in a photo that he or she is still at that age?

Comment: "This is Fred at 10 years of age ... and here is a current photo."

Comment: Similar to Hot Licks. This is a photo of Fred at age 10 .. and here is how Fred looks now.

Comment: @HotLicks could you turn that into a quick answer that can be upvoted to stop this question being bumped by community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd say something like "This is Fred at 10 years of age ... and here is a current photo."

If this is written rather than spoken you'd use those phrases (or simply "Fred at age 10", etc) as captions for the photos.  Or maybe, in associated text, "On the left is Fred at age 10, and on the right is Fred in 2017."

Answer (score 0):

"He was 70 years old when this photo was taken."
"He is 70 years old in this photo."

Comment: So, he is still say, 70 years old, I should say "He was 70 years old." right?

Comment: @MansurSegmen: His present age does not affect the tense you use when talking about a photgraph, so *was*,  though you could say "he was 70 years old in this photograph  (and still is)".

Comment: oh thanks, It's not that way in my first language (Turkish).

Comment: I don't think a reader would be confused with current or past tense, but you should try to use present tense whenever possible.

Comment: @MansurSegmen - That being the case, you might want to check out [ell.se], too.